# passing commands to application CLI from python script

Tags: python

To run shell command from python script, I generally use `subprocess` or `os.system` module.

Using that I am running some shell command from python script which is initiating another application and that application also has command line interface.

1. How would I pass commands to that application CLI from my python script?
2. How can I capture the output of application CLI from my python script?

It is highly appreciated if someone can suggest material or example code.

Answer (score 2):

The application you're initiating might behave differently when running through a subprocess. Specifically, when connected to a process pipe, some applications buffer their output by default instead of flushing line by line. If the application you're running flushes its output, you can get it realtime, otherwise, you'll only get output when the buffer is full.

That said, here's an example to run some application:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['someapp', 'param1', 'param2'], 
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)

# sends the command "some_command" to the app:
p.stdin.write('some_command\n') 

# waits for a single line from the output
result = p.stdout.readline()
```

If it hangs on `p.stdout.readline()` that means the output is being buffered.

Comment: Unwanted comma after stdout=subprocess.PIPE

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande extra comma there doesn't hurt.